# How to solve Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-headers, codeigniter-2

I have read all the answers regarding this error in stackoverflow and couldn't solve it...

There are no whitespaces before and after the opening of `<?php` tag... and anyway error is showing on line no. 2 ...

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/cctvbuzz/public_html/dev/lifetechadmin/application/models/Category_model.php:2)

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Line Number: 561

Backtrace:

File: /home/cctvbuzz/public_html/dev/lifetechadmin/application/controllers/Specifications.php
Line: 35
Function: redirect

File: /home/cctvbuzz/public_html/dev/lifetechadmin/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

And here is my Category_model first few line.. where line no. 2 is that class declaration.. So, what else could be the problem.. I also haven't used any function related to cookies....

```
class Category_Model extends CI_Model {
    function get_category($parent) {
        $this->db->select('category_id,category,parent');
        $this->db->where('parent',$parent);
        $this->db->from('category');
        $query = $this -> db -> get();
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the CI_Model class look like? Or do you have a __construct function running somewhere?

Comment: no i had __construct function but i had no use of it.. so i removed it...

Comment: Class name and file name should be like Category_model.php and `class Category_model extends CI_Model {}` first letter only upper case

Comment: Ohh That worked Thanks... But how that was anyhow related with headers... can you please tell me?

Comment: It probably gave an error message which meant the headers were already sent.